# Is there a list of major OpenID providers URIs that ZF knows how to work with?

Tags: php, zend-framework, openid

Is there a list of major OpenID providers URIs that ZF knows how to work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As OpenID is a standardized open protocol, then the OpenID consumer component of ZF can work with any OpenID provider.

Also, ZF implements a component to create your own provider.

Specifically, ZF [supports](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.openid.html#zend.openid.introduction.standards) the following OpenID standards:

- OpenID Authentication protocol version 1.1
- OpenID Authentication protocol version 2.0 draft 11
- OpenID Simple Registration Extension version 1.0
- OpenID Simple Registration Extension version 1.1 draft 1

So, any provider which implements any of the authentication protocols (and optionally any of the SRE for profile exchange) will work with ZF.

Comment: tried the google uri and tried the yahoo uri and it didn't work on the demo that ships with ZF. Also, I would like to build something similar to what SO does in the login page-another reason to have that list.

Comment: As http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html says, Google implements the OpenID 2.0 Directed Identity protocol which is not supported by Zend. I don't know about the other major companies (such as AOL, Microsoft and Yahoo, which claims to have OpenID support) but if it doesn't work maybe it's because of the same reason or some obscure reason. In my experience, none of the well-known companies works well with OpenID. The only ones that works well are the specific OpenID providers (not the "adapted" providers) such as http://www.myopenid.com